# In c++ we declare a vector like this. std::vector<int> v(6); how to do it for two dimensional vector

Tags: syntax, c++17

```
std::vector<int> v(6);
```

how to declare a two dimensional vector with limits like above code for one dimension

I'm a noob in c++. I tried like this:
`

```
std::vector<int> v(6)(2);
```

`
I expected a two dimensional vector with 6 rows and 2 columns to take input in.
I know how to declare 2d vector. I just wanted it with limit.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, there's no direct type which exactly represents a 2D "vector"/"matrix"/"tensor".

What you can create, is a vector of vectors. You'd write that as `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` - each element of the outer vector is itself a vector. But there's an important difference here: each of the inner vectors has its *own* length, and those could be different.

`vector` has a constructor taking a second argument, the initial value. You can use that here to initialize the inner vectors:

`std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(6, std::vector<int>(2));`